# Facial Recognition single source to database matching

Tags: python-3.x, face-recognition

For a college project I need to create a facial recognition system which uses a source photo to source a database for matches. So far I have the below, but that simply determines if there is a match or not and prints accordingly. How do I output matches to a local directory and name them appropriately ie. Match1, Match2 etc. Any help greatly appreciated.

Cheers - Julio

```
import face_recognition

picture_of_me = face_recognition.load_image_file('ImagesBasic/Clinton.jpg')
my_face_encoding = face_recognition.face_encodings(picture_of_me)[0]

unknown_picture = face_recognition.load_image_file('MultiPeople/face00.jpg')
unknown_face_encoding = face_recognition.face_encodings(unknown_picture)[0]

results = face_recognition.compare_faces([my_face_encoding], unknown_face_encoding)

if results[0] == True:
    print("Match")
else:
    print("No Match")
```

Comment: https://towardsdatascience.com/real-time-face-recognition-an-end-to-end-project-b738bb0f7348

this will surely help

Comment: hi, no this is for live facial matching. I've done this successfully in another project.